# Click once Application not launching in my Asp.Net/MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, clickonce

I have developed a desktop application which I published using Click Once, my intention is to be able to call up the application in my web application. But this is giving me the following error.
Please, I need help.

This is my Controller  Code

```
 public FilePathResult GetFile(string fileName= "TestingApplication.application")
    {

        var dir = Server.MapPath("~/Common/TestingApp/");
        var path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
        return File(path, GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(fileName)));
    }


private string GetMimeType(string extension)
    {
        if (extension == ".application" || extension == ".manifest")
            return "application/x-ms-application";
                    else if (extension == ".deploy")
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return "application/x-msdownload";
    }
```

Cannot download the application. The application is missing required files. Contact application vendor for assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I later got it working after days of sleepless night. The first thing i did was to delete the content cache on `C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\`. And I did rewrite the code to this.

```
 `     public ActionResult Download()
            {
                string path = @"~/Common/TestingApp/TestingApplication.application";
                return new RedirectResult(path);
            }`
```